# How do you view/debug :before and :after in a browser developer tools?

Tags: css, browser, pseudo-element, developer-tools

I'm trying to view/edit styles of an :after element in Developer Tools.

How may I find the rules associated to `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements?

Answer (score 5):

Found it. You select the element that has the :after and the :after styles will be listed with the other styles for that element.

Answer (score 0):

In Chromium browsers (e.g. **Chrome, Brave and Edge**), open the element's collapsed content and click on the automatically added `::after` element:

[image: Chromium browsers ::after pseudo-element][image]

**Firefox** though has an independent *Pseudo-elements* section on the right pane after you click directly on the original element:

[image: Firefox browser ::after pseudo-element]

**IE11** simply lists the `::after` rule together with other element rules when you click on it:

[image: IE11 browser ::after pseudo-element]